# Mapping through an undefined array using apply

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping

Can anyone explain the next weird behavior?

This works:

```
const defaultSides = 10;
const stats = Array.apply(null, { length: defaultSides }).map(() => 100);
// Array [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100]
```

This doesn't:

```
const stats2 = new Array(defaultSides);
const res = stats2.map(() => 100);
console.log(res)
//Array [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

I've already solved the problem using either Array.from or Array.of. However, I want to know what causes Javascript to still return me an undefined array after obviously having mapped through it in the second code block.

Answer (score 2):

`new Array(defaultSides)` creates a sparse array.

[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) iterates only non sparse items with the callback.

> Due to the algorithm defined in the specification, if the array which `map` was called upon is sparse, resulting array will also be sparse keeping same indices blank.

Answer (score 0):

`Array` constructor does different things depending on the number of arguments. If you give it a number value as it's sole argument it will set the array length property to that value. E.g.

```
let arr = [];
arr.length = val;
```

**This doesn't actually sets any value from property 0 to `val`.**

If you feed the `Array` constructor a list of values however (which is what your `apply` call is doing) it will create an array with those values.